# oracle plsql to mysql query update

Tags: mysql, oracle

Here A is a database and B is a table of A and C,D,E,F are columns of table B.

> UPDATE A.B SET C = (SELECT SUM(D) FROM A.B t2 WHERE t2.E=A.B.E AND t2.F=2013 GROUP BY E) WHERE F=2013;

This works fine in Oracle PL/SQL but gives the following error in MySQL:

> Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'B' for update in FROM clause 0.000 sec

I tried to solve it with:

> CREATE TABLE t2 AS select * FROM B;

and then modified the original query to become

> UPDATE A.B SET C = (SELECT sum(D) FROM t2 WHERE t2.E=A.B.E AND t2.F=2013 GROUP BY E) WHERE F=2013;

Now it takes ages to run and MySQL often crashes. Any pointers or help is appreciated. The same goes for any method of optimizing the query....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a JOIN:

```
UPDATE A.B t1
JOIN (SELECT E, SUM(D) sumD
      FROM A.B
      WHERE F = 2013
      GROUP BY E) t2
USING (E)
SET C = sumD
WHERE F = 2013
```

Comment: thanks... i was able to make this query run fast by indexing for E .... it worked !!

Answer (score 0):

> `UPDATE A.B SET C = (SELECT SUM(D) FROM A.B t2 WHERE t2.E=A.B.E AND t2.F=2013 GROUP BY E) WHERE F=2013;`

This is because your update could be cyclical... what if updating that record causes something to happen which made the WHERE condition FALSE? You know that isn't the case, but the engine doesn't. There also could be opposing locks on the table in the operation.